# Inline images and stacking

Tags: html, css, image, block

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code for this holder page. 
Something is breaking the format and I'm sure it has to do with inline-block and clearing boxes.

Could anyone steer me in the right direction? I've not made a page entirely from images before.

This line is saying it's 127px high when rendered - however the image is only 121px.

```
<a class="imageleft" href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" width="76" height="121"></a>
```

Can anyone see what I've missed here?

Site: 
http://michaelbirchall.com/etc/dvd-page/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The site's down. Could you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Weird, It's up for me... Try this link anyway? http://jsfiddle.net/2ZVVX/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there's an inherited `font-size`. It's also affecting your bottom row of images too, but it's not noticeable since there aren't any other images below it. Since your page is all images, setting that to 0 should be okay.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZVVX/6/

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Weird, does anyone know why this last image is sitting below the rest? http://michaelbirchall.com/etc/dvd-page/

Comment: Thanks for that. I was going about it the hard way... I re-made the images as you suggested. Sometimes it's good to walk away from a problem for a while.

Comment: Hmm, I've set font-size:0; margin:0; etc however there still appears to be small lines between the hover images? Is it just my screen? http://www.michaelbirchall.com/etc/dvd-page/

Comment: Looks okay for me on Safari, Firefox, and Chrome. Opera still has the line though, I'm not sure if the line-height is getting recalculated. Can additionally set line-height to 0 as suggested below and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`.imageleft` is an `inline-block` element, which means line heights affect it. Just set `line-height: 0` and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZVVX/5/

Comment: Really? You talking about the .container-content class? I just did that and it did nothing for me? http://jsfiddle.net/2ZVVX/3/

Comment: http://imgur.com/G8VG4Dd That's what I get even when I remove the margin: 0 auto from the container.

Comment: @michaelbirchall.com Sorry, didn't get your question. Updated answer to fix. The other problem is that with inline-block, elements have to be on the same level, which explains the second black space. You'll have to use relative positioning for that.